# Styled Componets suggestion not working on react

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

[image]

Can someone help me with styled-components ? I have installed styled-component in my react app . but when i am going to apply styled div the css suggestion or prefixes or css emmet not coming or showing. I have also install intellisence extension on my vs code. if someone having some suggestions or solutions plz net me know.

Comment: Take a look again at [ask]. SO doesn't use hashtags so I removed them from your question

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)